# How does javascript know the length of an array under the hood?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How does javascript know the length of an array under the hood, if it stores data of different types in an array.
For example in C we can find length like:

```
int arr[] = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};

int length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

printf("The length of the array is: %d\n", length);
```

Comment: Well, it’s a property on the array object. It gets incremented and decremented when certain things are done to the array. It’s not a value calculated from the size of elements.

Comment: Array is just only simple `object` and `length` is field in that object.

When you can some function change length of array such as: `push`, `unshift`. So, it changes the length and the content of this

Answer (score -3):

In JavaScript, you can get the size of an array in the same way, whatever its content.

```
let arr = [4, 'one', 15.6, false, 42];
console.log(`The length of the array is: ${arr.length}`); //The length of the array is: 5
```